# GIT_COMMITTER_DATE not recognized

Tags: git, github, gitlab

This is probably an extremely simple question but I'm trying to modify the date of a Git commit but whenever I try to modify the Git environment variables `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` or `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` I get this message.
When I type `git var -l` they don't show up either.
Do I have to add those variables myself?

```
C:\Users\MolinaBA\Desktop\MCPInfoGitMigrationTest>GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="12/12/12 4:40p +0000" git commit --amend --no-edit

'GIT_COMMITTER_DATE' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: You have to write "set" before GIT_COMMITTER_DATE

Comment: This is for a Unix/Linux shell, the Windows syntax is different

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to first [`set`](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/set.mspx?mfr=true) the `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` variable and then try `git commit --amend`. Shown below:

```
> set GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="12/12/12 4:40p +0000"
> git commit --amend --no-edit
```

Similar step for `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE`.

```
> set GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="12/12/12 4:40p +0000"
```

Comment: I am using the windows command prompt, not bash. I suppose I could just use git bash instead of the command prompt.

Comment: @molinab297 Check - `set` should do the same thing for you.

Comment: okay, that's what I thought I had to do. It doesn't add those variables to the git var file so I was confused. Works now. Thank you! @nash_ag

Comment: What's a "git var file"?

Answer (score 11):

If you are not using bash, you can set the variable just for this command with:

```
cmd /v /c "set GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=12/12/12 4:40p +0000&& git commit --amend --no-edit"
```

Note the lack of space before the `&&`. That is important or the value would have an extra space.

That way, you don't have to unset those variables once you are done using them got the `commit --amend`.
If you use the other answer, at least unset those variables:

```
set GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=
set GIT_AUTHOR_DATE=
```

Or any other `git commit` would use those dates!

But with the `cmd /v /c "..."`, you limit the variable to that command. It does not persist in your CMD session.

---

[ADTC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1134080/adtc) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44606452/git-committer-date-not-recognized/44606949#comment129766162_44606949):

> I managed to put this into an alias but only to remind me of the command and to get the head commit's author date (useful for amends):
>
> `cdate = !echo cmd /v /c \\\"set GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=\\&\\& git ca\\\" && git log -n 1 --format=%aD`
>
> Note: I still have to copy the output and construct the actual command.
> PS: ca is another alias I have for `commit --amend`.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to put this into an alias but only to remind me of the command and to get the head commit's author date (useful for amends): `cdate = !echo cmd /v /c \\\"set GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=\\&\\& git ca\\\" && git log -n 1 --format=%aD` **Note:** I still have to copy the output and construct the actual command. **PS:** `ca` is another alias I have for `commit --amend`.

Comment: @ADTC Thank you for this feedback. I have edited the answer and included your comment for more visibility.