# How to use git rebase to edit both author/committer and timestamps at the same time?

Tags: git, git-rebase

I've been trying to rewrite the history of a Git repository to consolidate commits, remove large files, and many other changes. `git filter-branch` is not recommended as a tool and I want the precision of rewriting the history manually.

I've run into a major obstacle. When I rewrite the commits, the rewritten commits show up as being committed by me (author authored and I committed), which I don't want.

I am able to get around this by running `git config user.name` and `git config user.email` before picking each commit in rebase. This makes it look like the original author committed it.

So far so good, but when I do this the committer timestamp is invariably "now". I can change the author timestamp with `git commit --amend --date`, but the committer timestamp is unchangeable.

I can use the option `--committer-date-is-author-date`, and that works (although it changes the timezone, which I don't like)...but seemingly not with an interactive rebase, where it does nothing. The automatic rebase does not permit me to use `git config user.name/email` to make the original author of the commit show up by themselves.

I have tried using `set GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=` followed by `git commit --amend --no-edit`. It was working at first, but then suddenly stopped working for an unknown reason. It simply does nothing now - the committer timestamp isn't affected.

This leaves me with a choice of having me added to the commits as the committer, or having an inaccurate timestamp of "now" in a project with years of history.

I'm looking for a way so that people looking at the history can see the original author and the original timestamp (or whatever ones I specify), and that is compatible with interactive rebase because I'm going to be doing a lot of rebasing, so the entire history will be rewritten from further and further in the past.

Yeah, this might be a crazy project, but does anyone have any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

(Yes, I am doing this on a separate branch. I will force push to the main branch after I have finished the project.)

EDIT: This is what happens when I try to set the environment variables as part of the rebase: https://gyazo.com/d6189169809023e2b722fedc03169011

(Using the following input: https://gyazo.com/8a38c243dac215c4a333394ef8fae78e)

I can set the environment variables using CMD, but Git can't do it: https://gyazo.com/39644a586b78cb933988e90880c67286

I am using Windows 10 Home Edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#_commit_information) `git commit` recognizes the following environment variables

```
GIT_AUTHOR_NAME
GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL
GIT_AUTHOR_DATE
GIT_COMMITTER_NAME
GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL
GIT_COMMITTER_DATE
```

Their values take precedence over the configuration values.

So in your case you need to set the `GIT_COMMITTER_*` variables.

You can check if `git` recognizes the variables by using the command

```
git var GIT_COMMITTER_IDENT
```

If it does not recognize them, make sure you are actually setting them. Setting and reading environment variables is OS dependent and can be tricky.

Comment: I have tried using these. It was originally working, but it does not work now. I don't know why.

Comment: @ShroudedEyes This sounds like a problem with setting the environment variables. Are you sure they are set correctly when calling `git`? Does ["git-committer-date-not-recognized"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44606452/git-committer-date-not-recognized) help? What OS are you using?

Comment: This is what happens when I try to set them as part of the rebase: https://gyazo.com/d6189169809023e2b722fedc03169011

Using the following input: https://gyazo.com/8a38c243dac215c4a333394ef8fae78e

Comment: git config user.name & git config user.email are functional, but don't change the timestamp.

I am using Windows 10 Home Edition.

Comment: I can set the environment variables using CMD, but Git can't do it: https://gyazo.com/39644a586b78cb933988e90880c67286

Comment: Ok, now I see: You want to change the environment variables inside of a `git rebase`. That is not how this works. Running some command from a rebase creates a new environment and does not modify the original one.
You might want to investigate using multiple calls to [`git cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) to do the rebase step by step on your own and setting the variables as needed before each of the cherry-picks.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I will proceed with the cherry picking.